# Merging two SQL queries with a common column name in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Maybe I'm making this far too complicated - I am trying to derive and then merge data from two tables. I have a table with questions (test_questions that shows if a given question was answered correct or incorrect) and a table with the users that took the questions (my_tests that has a user_id).  I can get the total number of distinct questions taken the first time by the user, scored correct or incorrect (and not null), with the following query:

```
with total_questions_by_user as (select distinct question_id, min(created_at), user_id
from test_questions
join my_tests
on test_questions.my_test_id = my_tests.id
where (correct = false or correct = true)
group by question_id, user_id)
select count(total_questions_by_user.question_id) as total_questions, total_questions_by_user.user_id as user_id
from total_questions_by_user
group by total_questions_by_user.user_id;
```

| total_questions | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 227 | 5 |
| 305 | 6 |

I can get the total number of distinct questions taken the first time by the user, scored correct, with the following nearly identical query:

```
with correct_questions_by_user as (select distinct question_id, min(created_at), user_id
from test_questions
join my_tests
on test_questions.my_test_id = my_tests.id
where correct = true
group by question_id, user_id)
select count(correct_questions_by_user.question_id) as correct_questions, correct_questions_by_user.user_id as user_id
from correct_questions_by_user
group by correct_questions_by_user.user_id;
```

| correct_questions | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 63 | 5 |
| 70 | 6 |

I'd like to combine these to get something like

| total_questions | user_id | incorrect_questions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 227 | 5 | 63 |
| 305 | 6 | 70 |

I've tried placing a `union all` between the queries which listed my users as different rows  in the same column (eg user 5 and 6 twice each) and displayed a single column of total_questions. I tried

```
select correct_questions, user_id, total_questions from total_questions_by_user
join correct_questions_by_user
on total_questions_by_user.user_id = correct_questions_by_user.user_id;
```

with the error "total_questions_by_user does not exist". Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need conditional aggregation:

```
select user_id, count(distinct question_id) as num_questions,
       count(distinct question_id) filter (where not correct) as in_correct_answers
from test_questions tq join
     my_tests t
     on tq.my_test_id = t.id
where correct = false or correct = true
group by user_id;
```

I'm not sure if the `count(distinct)` is necessary, but your query seems to suggest that a question can appear more than once in the `join`.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's fantastic. The questions appear multiple times. I think I ran into a small problem with duplicates if a person had a question_id that was correct = true and then repeated as correct = false or vice versa, so I assumed the user got the question incorrect the first time. So I wrote the same query as you but added the column ```  count(distinct question_id) - count(distinct question_id) filter (where correct = false) as recalculated_correct_answers```